# Configure Firefox Searchengine to use DuckDuckGo in German

Tags: firefox

I want to change the default langauge, DuckDuckGo uses when I start a search. What I already tried to do is simply add DuckDuckGo to my search bar. I also installed their addon. Both works if I configure on the DuckDuckGo homepage to use german by default. But since I erase all my firefox cookies by default on logout, I have to restore that setting each time.
The default config for DDG is to use the standard language of the browser I think. So maybe that is configured wrong?

Using Google I can change the language easy by using:
https://www.google.com/?hl=de
https://www.google.com/?hl=fr
....

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

If you have the add-on installed and can use DD from the search bar:

`sudo gedit /usr/lib/firefox/distribution/searchplugins/locale/en-US/duckduckgo.xml`

and the follow line at the bottom of the other Param's:

> <Param name="hl" value="DE"/>

Save and Close, Reboot firefox and try searching.

**OPTION 2**

Install the Add to Search Bar addon and restart firefox:

[Add to Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/)

Visit the DD homepage, right click the search bar and click "Add to search bar"

In the keyword field, enter "hl=DE"

Save and restart firefox.

Make sure the search you just added is selected (there may be a duplicate but this can be sorted by "managing search

Comment: I tried OPTION 2, but it didnt work. I also removed all the search engines except of google and DD, but the results are still in english.